# How to convert between bitmap (.bmp) file format types using mogrify?

Tags: bitmap, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, imagemagick-convert, scikit-image

How can I convert these BMP files to an older format?

I tried:

```
mogrify -format bmp -define bmp:format=bmp4 *.bmp
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"BMP4" is the newer format.  Try BMP2 or BMP3 instead, to get an older format.

Comment: Thank you a million times. I got a few BMP files from my designer but windows packager (`nsis.exe`) wouldn't accept them. Ran this above command with `bmp:format=bmp2` and now it is happy.